# How to take the results from an object/model and assign that value to a text-box or another variable. similar to assigning the results to a list-box

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am able to retrieve data from my database via stored procedure and then get that data to display in a list box easy.
NOTE i am also using dapper.

Now i want to bind that data in a text-box or a string variable, as the data doesn't need a list box its only one single string.

```
        //my class is located in a class library



        public string LocationName { get; set; } 

        public string Image_Path { get; set; } 

        public string FullImagepath { get { return Image_Path; } 

        }
```

I want to display the actual string value in the text-box not the generic list path.

This is the result that i get in the text-box i have replaced my actual project name however.

```
     System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MY PROJECT NAME.Library.Internal.DataAccess.]
```

Comment: What is the structure of the `Locations_Info` class? The reason you're getting the generic class name is because you can't stringify classes.

Comment: public class Locations_Info


        public string LocationName { get; set; }


public string Image_Path { get; set; }



}
public string FullImagepath
{
    get
    {
        return Image_Path;
    }

}

Comment: i can stringify the results that are returned if i pass that result to a listbox and then from the list box to a string. I think there is a way to bypass the listbox tho just havent figured out how to bind the result to a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply print off a list of classes, since C# won't know how to stringify the individual classes.

Instead, you can select parts of the class to print, using `System.Linq`, by selecting a string from each class, and then joining them together, like so:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(loadedLocations.Select(x => x.LocationName), ", ");
```

Or, if you want to list all properties, you could just use a loop to string build:

```
string final = "";
foreach (var location in loadedLocations)
{
    final += location.LocationName + " - Image at " + location.Image_Path + "\n";
}
textBox1.Text = final;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. i think i am not explaining well enough . i will try to explain better what i want

Comment: maybe if you skipped through the you-tube video you would have a better idea as to what am trying to accomplish.

Comment: That video is over an hour long, could you provide a timestamp of what you're specifically talking about?

Comment: 44:55-45:55 i have all this code working and returning the desired values 49:19 i want to make a variable data-source instead of the list-box 1:01:09 i am getting the required data at this location. 1:02:26-1:02:47 i want to place the data in a variable instead of in the list box.

Comment: Thanks guys i figured out how to bind the results to text-box successfully.